# According to Biblical Unitarians, was Jesus sinless?

Tags: life-of-jesus, sin, biblical-unitarian

Not much to add here - I need to ask this question as a pre-cursor to my next question. So, according to Biblical Unitarians, was Jesus sinless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Biblical unitarians (BU's) are a collection of people who combine a strong view about the Bible with a view that the Bible does not teach that God is more than 1 person, and therefore that Jesus is not God. Rather, the Father is God.

Although unitarianism impinges on various other theological beliefs in various ways, I don't think it effects this one directly. As with standard trinitarian belief, BU's would hold that Jesus is without sin. See 1 Peter 1:19 ("the precious blood of Jesus Christ, a lamb without blemish or defect"), 2 Corinthians 5:21 ("who knew no sin"), Hebrews 4:15 ("one who has been tempted in all things as we are, yet without sin"), 1 John 3:5 ("in Him there is no sin"), and so on.

As the BU article [Jesus is the Son of God, not God the Son](https://www.biblicalunitarian.com/articles/jesus-is-the-son-of-god-not-god-the-son) says

> "He is the only begotten Son of God, who loved so much that he lived a
> sinless, obedient life and died on the cross for us[.]"

However, BU's would hold that Jesus could sin as He is a man, which would distinguish them from some trinitarians who hold that Jesus can't sin as He is God, as in the article [Was Jesus sinless?](https://www.gotquestions.org/Jesus-sinless.html) where it states

> "[A]s Jesus Christ is God, He has no capacity to sin."